# How to enable powerchime on Big Sur when power cable disconnects

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power

By default, a power chime sounds when I plug in the power cable to my Macbook Pro. It is a nice thing to let me know when the machine is plugged in.

But nothing similar happens when the power cable disconnects.

Sometimes the power plug accidentally disconnects because I turned the computer around or move a little bit and I can not notice it if I am concentrated on other things or working on fullscreen. After a while, I realize the MacBook is running on battery and the battery is drained. This happens a lot and it unnecessarily ages the battery.

Is there a way to make macOS play a sound when the power cable disconnects (like it does when the power cable is plugged in) or/and show a notification on the screen?